# ng.Router not defined using Angular 2 pure JS (no typescript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to define a route using Angular 2 Pure JS.  There are very few examples on this.  I am getting the error "ng.router is not defined." I have included
script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.14/router.dev.js">
 in the main HTML file.  I am seeing the 
import {component} from @angular/router
 but that is only ts, correct? How do i import using pure JS?

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags. You say it's pure JS (no typescript), so don't add the typescript tag.

Comment: the `import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; ` is the ES6 way to import modules. Its the same in pure JS with ES6 and TS

Comment: but then i get an error saying token "import" is invalid?

Comment: Then you don't use ECMAScript 6 as a standard. You should setup [babeljs](https://babeljs.io/) to get all the benifits for angular2. Otherwise you need to write it the old way.
Have a look here https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-equivalents-in-es5